# Appending missing values according to index

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Say if i have a tensor

```
values = torch.tensor([5, 3, 2, 8])
```

and a corresponding `index` to `values`

```
index = torch.tensor([0, 2, 4, 5])
```

and assuming that I want to insert in the missing index `(1 and 3)`, with a fixed value `(100)`, such that I get

```
values = torch.tensor([5, 100, 3, 100, 2, 8])
```

Is there a vectorized way to do it in PyTorch (or numpy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill it with 100 first and then fill it with the original values.

in pytorch

```
import torch

result = torch.empty(6, dtype = torch.int32).fill_(100)
values = torch.tensor([5, 3, 2, 8], dtype = torch.int32)
index = torch.tensor([0, 2, 4, 5])
result[index] = values
print(result)
```

in numpy

```
import numpy as np

result = np.full((6,), 100)
index = np.array([0, 2, 4, 5])
values = np.array([5, 3, 2, 8])
result[index] = values
print(result)
```